# JDBC connect string to sqlrelay

Tags: oracle, jdbc, proxy

I want to proxy all DB connections to a Oracle DB over SQL relay. I have managed to install the tool and my configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE instances SYSTEM "sqlrelay.dtd">
<instances>
    <instance id="oracletest" dbase="oracle">
            <users>
                    <user user="oracletest" password="oracletest"/>
            </users>
            <connections>
                    <connection string="user=<confidential>;password=<confidential>;oracle_sid=<confidential>"/>
            </connections>
    </instance>
</instances>
```

I can connect to the database using the SQL relay provided tool like:

```
λ sqlrsh -id oracletest
sqlrsh - Version 0.65.0
    Connected to: localhost:9000 as oracletest

    type help; for help.

0> select * from dual;
DUMMY
=====
X

    Rows Returned   : 1
    Fields Returned : 1
    Elapsed Time    : 0.055000 sec
```

I try to connect to SQL relay by using SQL Developer and JDBC by providing a connect string like

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:oracletest/oracletest@localhost:9000:<SID>
```

but I can't figure out what the SID should be (oracletest, oracle seems not to work). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JDBC URL starts `jdbc:oracle:thin:` then that means you want to use the Oracle JDBC driver which is typically used to connect to an Oracle Database. However, here you want to connect to Sqlrelay.

Sqlrelay doesn't have a native JDBC driver. You have to use an JDBC-ODBC bridge to connect to it. This is described in this documentation:
http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/programming/jdbc.html